# Wrong redirect after post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

While posting form with miltiple images i get different redirect than while posting on local.
Online server has Phusion Passenger Apache/nginx.
Local Server uses standard Webrick.
Rails 3.0.9

Application is internationalized (2 languages) English and Croatian

On Local machine there is no problem it redirects perfectly.
http://localhost:3000/en/references

Online Server redirects with extra language segment in URL.
http://somesite.com/en/en/references

This throws error, page doesn't exist.

controller update action:

```
def update
  @reference = Reference.find(params[:id])
  if @reference.update_attributes(params[:reference])
    redirect_to(references_path, :notice => 'Reference was successfully updated.')
  else
    render :action => "edit"
  end
end
```

Routes are handled like this.

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /hr|en/ do
  resources :references
  resources :reference_groups
  resources :pages
  resources :photos
end
```

Log output from server is:

```
Started POST "/hr/references/1" for 78.0.196.78 at Wed Nov 23 12:55:11 +0100 2011
  Processing by ReferencesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"reference"=>{"name_en"=>"Test Reference", "position"=>"1"...}
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving /home/alfaplan/alfaplan/public/images/photos/medium/katalog-zaks_012-l.jpg
[paperclip] saving /home/alfaplan/alfaplan/public/images/photos/thumb/katalog-zaks_012-l.jpg
[paperclip] saving /home/alfaplan/alfaplan/public/images/photos/original/katalog-zaks_012-l.jpg
Redirected to http://alfaplan.host25.com/hr/hr/references
Completed 302 Found in 1344ms

Started GET "/hr/hr/references" for 78.0.196.78 at Wed Nov 23 12:55:12 +0100 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/hr/hr/references"):
```

Any ideas where the problem might be?

I am fairly new to RoR and this is my first question here.

Comment: How do you manage the language segment in your routes?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use optional parameters `(:locale)` here. Can you try without parentheses? And have a look at `production.log` to see where did it redirected, `en/references` or `/en/en/references`?

Comment: @ShiningRay Removing parentheses didn't do anything. This code is from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).
I will put log details in question.

Comment: Given that the major difference is apache on prod... do you have some apache rewrite rules that will rewrite domain/url to, say domain/en/url ?

Comment: It's interesting that thist error occurs only when i'm uploading photo with other form data. Otherwise it posts ok, with only one language segment.

Comment: @Taryn East No rewrite rules that I'm aware of. RewriteEngine off in .htaccess file.

Comment: where does paperclip get it's url (Redirected to http://alfaplan.host25.com/hr/hr/references) from?

Comment: @phoet I think that Paperclip urls are handled automatically.
"Redirected to http://alfaplan.host25.com/hr/hr/references" comes from controller > update action "redirect_to(references_path, :notice => 'Reference was successfully updated.')"

Comment: @phoet This just might be an Paperclip error after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it goes.

It seems to be a Paperclip - Apache bug.

Disabling mod_security in Apache cconfiguration, or if available in .htaccess file prevents doubling your URL segment.

Disabling mod_security isn't very smart so people from hosting are now trying to isolate mod_security rule which is causing the problem.

Pulled answer here http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=42079.

Comment: i would appreciate if you flag my comment as helpful if it pointed you to the right direction ;)

Comment: This issue still exists.  Do you have any idea how mod_security can be configured to avoid the problem?

Comment: @KenB Sorry, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like apache/ nginx issue. Check to be sure your have the rewrite module enabled in the setup as sometimes this could be causing the issue

Comment: Guys from hosting say's that it's enabled.